# Sylius eCommerce Framework (Symfony) - How to create a product with price?

Tags: symfony, sylius

How to create programmatically a product with price on Sylius Framework?

Here is how I create a product:

```
$factory = $this->container->get('sylius.factory.product');
$manager = $this->container->get('sylius.manager.product');
$product = $factory->createNew();
$product
  ->setName('FOO - '.$title);
$product->setCode($this->generateRandomString());
$product->setSlug($this->generateRandomString());
$manager->persist($product);
$manager->flush();
```

When I try to attach the price, there is an error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "setPrice" of class "Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product".

For the products created without price, I can't even set a price later in the Admin Interface, there is no field.

[image]

I think it's related with the "Simple Product" VS "Configurable Product" differences. When I create a **Simple Product** from admin interface, I can then modify the Price:

[image]

How can create programmatically a **Simple Product** instead a **Configurable Product**

Answer (score 0):

With a quick glance at the Sylius source code, it looks like the pricing is managed in the ChannelPricing class. As such, you'll need to create a ChannelPricing object.

More information:
http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/products/pricing.html